# Read command-line arguments in SML

Tags: sml

I am trying to read the name of my input file that is argv[1] . This is what I’ve done so far :

```
val args = CommandLine.arguments() ;
val (x::y) =  args ;
val _ = agora x
```

but I keep getting this error message :

```
uncaught exception Bind [nonexhaustive binding failure] .
```

Can anyone help ? Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the compiler warning you that you can't be sure that the bind pattern always holds.

For example, given the following program:

```
val args = CommandLine.arguments ()
val (x::y) = args
val _ = print (x ^ "\n")
```

Compiling and running this gives:

```
$ mosmlc args.sml
$ ./a.out Hello
Hello
$ ./a.out
Uncaught exception:
Bind
```

To safely handle a variable amount of command-line arguments, you might use a *case-of*:

```
fun main () =
    case CommandLine.arguments () of
         []     => print ("Too few arguments!\n")
       | [arg1] => print ("That's right! " ^ arg1 ^ "\n")
       | args   => print ("Too many arguments!\n")

val _ = main ()
```

Compiling and running this gives:

```
$ mosmlc args2.sml
$ ./a.out 
Too few arguments!
$ ./a.out hello
That's right! hello
$ ./a.out hello world
Too many arguments!
```

A side note: The equivalent of C's `argv[0]` is `CommandLine.name ()`.